# python RE vs html5 RE

Tags: python, regex, html

it seems that i got a bug in python: (Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)

```
>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}", "0775123456") #match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002D3FC60>

>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}", "077512345") #dont match

>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}", "07751234567") #match!
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002D3F920>

>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}","07751234567777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777") #match!!
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002D3FC60>
```

so i must use the dollar sign to limit "exactly" the numer!
i think it's a bug, because in HTML5 validation, the {7} means "exactly" 7 digits, and here in python, it seems that it means "at least"
and here is how it behaves using the dollars sign:

```
>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}$", "0775123456") #match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002D3F920>

>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}$", "07751234567") #dont match

>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}$", "077512345") #dont match
```

and this happens to all other regular expression, not only the exact number matching, the dollar must be added!

so is it a bug? or it's by design?

Comment: It is not a bug. However, I did not downvote it.

Comment: @Tadeck Surely a *question* doesn't have to be correct. Answers should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. `re.match` matches at the beginning of a string as opposed to `re.search`, which matches anywhere in a string. Extra characters after the string are ignored. See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match for more details.

Other languages that also use regular expressions, such as grep and perl, act the same. Regular expressions are primarily used for searching text.

If you want to perform an exact match you have to specify the dollar sign as you yourself also noted.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) states:

> If zero or more characters *at the beginning* of string match the regular expression pattern…

(Emphasis mine.)

This means that all the characters in the string after the match completes are ignored. For instance, the following would also work:

```
>>> re.match("0[5-7][5-9][0-9]{7}", "0775123456abc")
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x10ee2e8b8>
```

Regular expressions don't really specify where, if anywhere, a match has to be anchored. For instance, Python also has [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) which by default isn't anchored at the beginning either. You can always explicitly specify anchoring using the `^` and `$` metacharacters.

Comment: thank you, and also, dident know about re.search, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

As others have said... not a bug, your regex doesn't make it clear why '$' seems to fix it, but this example should:

```
import re

print 'food: ',
print re.match('fo{2}d', 'food')     # match found!

print 'fooood: ',
print re.match('fo{2}d', 'fooood')   # no match!
```

*anything* after the `{}` will give you the behavior you want, if you want the string to end after the digits, then `$` is the appropriate *anything* to add there.

Comment: -1: The OP already knows how to fix the problem, he's asking why it occurs. You're just repeating what's already in the question.

Comment: @millimoose I understand he knows the `$` fixes it... he said it seemed the `{n}` notation indicated `n` or more instances, when that is clearly not what is happening... I was just trying to illustrate that more clearly.  The *problem* really has nothing to do with the `{n}`, and I wasn't sure if the OP was aware of that.

Comment: thank you for the answer, am sorry, am a beginner, and now i get more and more python code :D

Comment: @AdamWagner Fair enough, I suppose "It's not a bug, here's an example that this works correctly" is a valid answer to "Is this a bug?"

Comment: @millimoose Yeah.. mine is not really a good stand-alone answer... more of an addition to yours and Hans'.  I just figured I didn't need to repeat what you put in your answer.