# URLS Mixed up with django

Tags: django, url, django-models, django-views

It seems like Django does not differentiate my urls really well. If I want to display my photo/add page then I have to delete the photo/ url otherwise Django will always return the same 'Photo-List' url.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from photo import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'$', views.ListImage.as_view(),name ='Photo-List',),
    url(r'add$', views.ImageCreate.as_view(), name = 'create-image',),
    url(r'display/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ImageView.as_view(),name='image-view',),
    url(r'update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ImageUpdate.as_view(),name='image-update',),

) 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, UpdateView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse
from photo.models import Tag, Image, Album
from django.conf import settings

class ListImage(ListView):
    #context_object_name = 'object_list'
    template_name = 'image_list.html'
    model = Image

class ImageView(DetailView):
    model = Image
    template_name = 'image.html'

class ImageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Image
    template_name='image_create.html'
    fields = ['title','image']
    success_url=reverse_lazy('create-image')
```

Also, other major problem, I cannot make my Detail view work. If I try to access photo/display/2, I get a 404 saying no Image matches the query. This is a very important project for me, I really hope someone can help me. Adding my models.py in there just in case

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from string import join
import os


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def images(self):
        lst = [x.image.name for x in self.image_set.all()]
        lst = ["<a href='/media/%s'>%s</a>" % (x, x.split('/')[-1]) for x in lst]
        return join(lst, ', ')
    images.allow_tags = True

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12509831/1326943) might help. Try adding an initial caret character(`'^'`) to your url regex

Comment: Thanks Charl, I will try that tonight. DO you think this is why it wont pick <pk> in my detailview?